# Google Map API: How to skip loading tiles if current zoom level > max zoom level at special area

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm working on Google Map API v3.

But when zoom in with big level zoom at Sea Area. Google Map API return 404 error.

But on https://www.google.com/maps/@28.5698026,-78.3196671,8000m/data=!3m1!1e3

It's still working without 404 Error. Look like they skip loading new tiles if Google Map API return 404? I'm not sure about this.

This is my result:

[image]

This is Google Map result:

[image]

Thank you for reading my question!

Comment: This is smelling like a bug. Report it in [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com).

Comment: @xomena I already report to Google

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62396136

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Maximum Zoom Image Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maxzoom%20*Maximum%20Zoom%20Image%20Service*) to get the current maximum zoom Google has for imagery at a given location. You can connect this to the `center_changed` event to react to the user panning the map.

I wrote a small example on how to do this here:
https://jsfiddle.net/SirWolf/m684t5yp/

There is however no way to have a mix of different zoom levels in one view.